# Unity - OnTriggerEnter bullet ricochet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have some problems with simple ballistics.As i am new to coding and i wasted 2 days with searching, i decided to ask a question. I have a problem with my bullet.cs script, code works fine, except ricochet part. I used OnTriggerEnter beacuse bullets will penetrate different materials, but will bounce under specific angles, so i used collider as a trigger only. I know it can be dobe using OnCollisionEnter to determine normal and use Vector3.Reflect. But if collider is not set as a trigger only, bullets will be bouncing off from everithing a will never penetrate a wall. Just need a help with ricochet part on the bottom.

```
public Rigidbody rb;

private float vel;
private float kEnergy;

private bool AP = false;
private bool HP = false;
private bool ricochet = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    vel = 738f;
    kEnergy = 2108f;
    //HP == false;
    Destroy (gameObject, 10);
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    rb.velocity = transform.forward * vel;
    Quaternion bulletRotaion = transform.rotation;
    Debug.Log (bulletRotaion.eulerAngles);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    float curVelocity = rb.velocity.magnitude;
    if (curVelocity <= 0)
    {
        curVelocity = 0f;
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider c)
{
    if (c.tag == "Wall") {

        Quaternion localOffset = transform.rotation;
        float impactAngleX = c.gameObject.GetComponent <MaterialDensity> ().angleX;
        float impactAngleY = c.gameObject.GetComponent <MaterialDensity> ().angleY;
        float impactAngleZ = c.gameObject.GetComponent <MaterialDensity> ().angleZ;
        float angleX = localOffset.eulerAngles.x;
        float angleY = localOffset.eulerAngles.y;
        float angleZ = localOffset.eulerAngles.z;
        float density = c.gameObject.GetComponent <MaterialDensity> ().materialDensity;
        float ricochetX = (angleX + impactAngleX);
        if (ricochetX > 360) 
        {
            ricochetX = (ricochetX - 360);
        }

        if (ricochetX < 0) 
        {
            ricochetX = (ricochetX + 360);
        }
        float ricochetY = (angleY + impactAngleY);
        if (ricochetY > 360) 
        {
            ricochetY = (ricochetY - 360);
        }

        if (ricochetY < 0) 
        {
            ricochetY = (ricochetY + 360);
        }
        float ricochetZ = (angleZ + impactAngleZ);
        if (ricochetZ > 360) 
        {
            ricochetZ = (ricochetZ - 360);
        }

        if (ricochetZ < 0) 
        {
            ricochetZ = (ricochetZ + 360);
        }

        if ((ricochetX > 60 && ricochetX < 300) || (ricochetY > 60 && ricochetY < 300) || (ricochetZ > 60 && ricochetZ < 300)) {
            ricochet = true;
            //Debug.Log (ricochet);
        } 

        if ((ricochetX < 60 && ricochetX > 300) || (ricochetY < 60 && ricochetY > 300) || (ricochetZ < 60 && ricochetZ > 300)) {
            ricochet = false;
            //Debug.Log (ricochet);
        }

        Debug.Log (ricochet);
        Debug.Log (ricochetX);
        Debug.Log (ricochetY);
        Debug.Log (ricochetZ);

        if (AP) 
        {
            density *= 0.9f;
        }
        if (HP) 
        {
            density *= 3f;
        }

        //float vel = gameObject.GetComponent<GunNew>().velocity;
        float curVelocity = rb.velocity.magnitude;
        float velocityMod = curVelocity / vel;
        float densityMod = density / velocityMod;
        float curEnergy = (kEnergy * velocityMod);
        float energyMod = (curEnergy * velocityMod);
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        //Quaternion localOffset = transform.rotation;
        float randomX = Random.Range (0.03f, 0f);
        float randomY = Random.Range (0.03f, -0.03f);
        if (randomX == 0) 
        {
            randomX = 0.01f;
        }
        if (randomY == 0) 
        {
            randomY = 0.01f;
        }
        localOffset.x += randomX;
        localOffset.y += randomY;

        if (curVelocity > densityMod && !ricochet) {
            rb.rotation = localOffset;
            rb.velocity = transform.forward * ((curVelocity - (curVelocity * (randomX + randomY))) - densityMod);

            //Debug.Log (curVelocity);
            //Debug.Log (energyMod);
        } 

        if (curVelocity > densityMod && ricochet)
        {
            Vector3 objAngle = new Vector3 (impactAngleX, impactAngleY, impactAngleZ);
            Vector3 bulletAngle = rb.rotation.eulerAngles;
            Debug.Log (objAngle);
        }

        if (curVelocity <= densityMod)
        {
            //Debug.Log (curVelocity);
            //Debug.Log (energyMod);
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

second code is a code from wall.

```
public float materialDensity = 100f;
public float angleX;
public float angleY;
public float angleZ;

//Quaternion localOffset = transform.rotation;

// Use this for initialization
public void Start () 
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    Quaternion localOffset = transform.rotation;
    float angleX = localOffset.eulerAngles.x;
    float angleY = localOffset.eulerAngles.y;
    float angleZ = localOffset.eulerAngles.z;
    //Debug.Log (localOffset.eulerAngles.x);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
```

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but have you considered using two colliders, a trigger one and a normal one, then you disable the normal one as you pass through surfaces that you want to penetrate.

Comment: You mean something like a collider will be activated only if ricochet = true? I just found that whole angle determining need to be redone to use world rotation not a localOffset :( It is possible to use object rotation and bullet rotation do get angle, then reflect it and use as a new rotation for bullet?

Comment: Yea, that is what I was thinking. As for your second question, maybe but I don't have Unity in front of me to play around with so I don't know for sure how to do it.

Comment: I would advise against object rotations to determine angle of impact - this is rather inflexible, since if the bullet strikes your object from a different side, the calculation would almost inevitably be wrong. An easier option is to perform a raycast from the front of the bullet, and if it hits a face, use the bullet's `forward` vector and the `RaycastHit`'s `normal` vector to determine the angle of impact.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would make a layers in your game for things that will ricochet, and things that don't.

Then when you test for collisions with your bullet you can only check for collisions with the ricochet layer. This will increase  performance and also make coding much simpler.

From there you could rely on unity's physics to do it's own ricochet, or if you wanted to calculate it yourself you could do a raycast and use the raycast's normal as described above.

if(Physics.Raycast (shootRay, out shootHit, range, ricochetMask)) {
...